# Make sidebar sticky on page scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, sticky

I'm trying to make the sidebar of my page sticky on page scroll.

I've tried different solution but it doesn't work...

Here my last attempt:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  console.log( "document ready!" );

  var $sticky = $('.sticky');
  var $stickyrStopper = $('.sticky-stopper');
  if (!!$sticky.offset()) { // make sure ".sticky" element exists

    var generalSidebarHeight = $sticky.innerHeight();
    var stickyTop = $sticky.offset().top;
    var stickOffset = 0;
    var stickyStopperPosition = $stickyrStopper.offset().top;
    var stopPoint = stickyStopperPosition - generalSidebarHeight - stickOffset;
    var diff = stopPoint + stickOffset;

    $(window).scroll(function(){ // scroll event
      var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // returns number

      if (stopPoint < windowTop) {
          $sticky.css({ position: 'absolute', top: diff });
      } else if (stickyTop < windowTop+stickOffset) {
          $sticky.css({ position: 'fixed', top: stickOffset });
      } else {
          $sticky.css({position: 'absolute', top: 'initial'});
      }
    });

  }
});
```

Here the source code of my page: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bPareG

Can anyone of you help me please ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you don't mind it just staying put in really old browsers (looking at you IE) you can ditch the JavaScript and use position: sticky

Comment: why not letting the sidebar on `position: fixed` ?

Comment: You didn't include jQuery in your Codepen.io so right now it will simply fail to run your JS code. Here's a [fork](https://codepen.io/AlexWayhill/pen/PrEOVX) of your code and at least it has a sliding sidebar, even if the position currently overlaps the rest of the contents. Could you let us know how you would want the sidebar to appear, compared to the rest of the contents?

Comment: @SaschaM78, thanks for your help. The sidebar should appears on the right of the page. Could you please help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As was also recommended in the comment by robinvrd, I would use position fixed as it avoids the hassle with calculating the new Y-position (better said, the browser takes care of this internally). So assuming you want your sticky box to scroll until it reaches the end of the view port and then remains visible on the side, this would be a solution:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  // scroll event
  var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // returns number

  if (stickyTop < windowTop + stickOffset) {
    $sticky.css({ position: "fixed", top: 0, right: 0 });
  } else {
    $sticky.css({ position: "absolute", top: "initial", right: 0 });
  }
});
```

The changed code can be found in the mentioned [Codepen](https://codepen.io/AlexWayhill/pen/PrEOVX).